# How to fetch all the values in a List after a particular value using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list

```
List<int> lister = new List<int> {1,3,2,4,6}
```

I need to get all the values of the list after a specified value. Suppose if I select 2, I should get 4 and 6 back. I know this can be done using foreach/for but I was asked in an interview to use LINQ to solve this and I couldn't. Can someone tell the syntax to use LINQ?

Comment: `lister.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).Skip(1)` that will skip until it sees the 2 and then skips the 2.

Comment: What is the reason behind downvoting the question? Have I broken any rule of posting on StackOverflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var index = lister.IndexOf(2) + 1;
var newList = lister.Skip(index).ToList();
```